Advice needed to load images on looping page
I have a gallery page using the Image Photo Gallery Final Tiles Grid WordPress plugin.
I want the page/scroll to continuously repeat (so as a user scroll down the page the gallery is repeated.
The following script seems to do the repeating nicely but the images aren't loading and I can't seem to figure it out, any ideas?
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    const $gallery = $(".final-tiles-gallery");
    const originalContent = $gallery.html(); // Save the original gallery content

    // Function to append the content again
    function appendContent() {
        $gallery.append(originalContent); // Duplicate the gallery content

        // Re-initialize the gallery plugin after appending new content
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Trigger the gallery plugin to reprocess the newly added images
            if (typeof jQuery.fn.ftgInit === 'function') {
                $gallery.ftgInit(); // This is specific to the Final Tiles Gallery plugin
            }

            // Ensure the gallery layout is recalculated after new images are appended
            const instance = $gallery.data('ftg-instance'); // Get the gallery instance
            if (instance) {
                instance.setCurrentColumnSize(); // Recalculate column size for layout
                instance.setCurrentImageSizeFactor(); // Adjust image size factor for new content
                instance.setCurrentGridSize(); // Adjust grid size for the new layout
                instance.refresh(); // Recalculate and refresh layout
            }
        }, 100); // Adjust the timeout delay as needed
    }

    // Trigger infinite scroll
    jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
        const scrollPosition = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height(); // Current scroll position
        const documentHeight = jQuery(document).height(); // Total document height

        // If the user scrolls near the bottom, append more content
        if (scrollPosition >= documentHeight - 100) {
            appendContent();
        }
    });
});

Here's the page if it helps...
Looping gallery
Many thanks (in advance)!

img tags created are missing src attribute, that's why they don't show. Looking to your code, the only clue I find is it would be to the ftginit function which appears to be specific to your plugin.
